# So many way to instantiate a new Readable stream object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I have seen many way of instantiating a readable stream in Node.js, and I am a little bit confused.

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var rs1 = Readable(); // the first way
var rs2 = new Readable; // the second way
var rs3 = new Readable(); // the third way
```

Are they exactly the same? If not, what are the differences?

Comment: 2+3 are the same thing, 1 depends on the wiring of the "constructor".

Comment: `new X` is “shorthand” for `new X()`. They’re equivalent. As for `Readable()`, it might work, but it’s a constructor, so *never* omit `new`. Bad habit.

Answer (score 2):

For `stream.Readable`, they're all equivalent.

When called as a `function` (without `new`), a `new` instance [will be created anyways](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.25/lib/_stream_readable.js#L100-L102):

```
function Readable(options) {
  if (!(this instanceof Readable))
    return new Readable(options);

  // ...
}
```

And, when called as a constructor (with `new`), the [parenthesis are simply optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) when no arguments are given.

> Syntax
>
> ```
> new constructor[([arguments])]
> ```